# Size of split views in UISplitViewController? No hard-coded values please

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ipad

I'm building view hierarchies programmatically, without using a nib, for the master and the detail views in the UISplitViewController. My problem is that I do not know how large those views are. Well, of course, I know their hard-coded values... But I want to be a good citizen and not use hard-coded values and instead query them. Problem is that I have no idea how... Do you?

Thanks in advance,
/Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by accessing the viewControllers property of split view and it's the 2nd view's frame in the array that is returned.

What is the hard coded value?